# What is protected once an object declared const c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

If i have the following:

```
class Array{
public:
Array (int n=2) : _n(n), buf(new int[n]) {}

int & operator[](int i) const
{
return _buf[i];
}

int _n;
int* _buf;
};



int main()
{
Array arr1;
const Array arr2;

arr1[0]=1;
arr1[1]=2;

arr2[0]=arr1[0];
++arr2[0];

std:: << arr2[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

the program will compile and will print '2', but im a bit confused.

what does the const declaration in arr2 protects exactly?

obviously not the content of the object?

please help me to understand.

thank you!

Comment: It's because you didn't indent your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ compiler only enforces that `const` will protect the members of this object, not other objects referenced indirectly (e.g. via pointer).  `_buf` is a pointer member and what it points to is not protected by the compiler.

However, many classes override based on `const` in order to also protect access to associated objects.  To do that, you'd write:

```
int & operator[](int i) { return _buf[i]; }
const int & operator[](int i) const { return _buf[i]; }
```

This propagates `const` on the object to `const` on the subscripted element.